# Creating classes for nested blocks in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to reformat some helpers in my Rails views. I want a syntax similar to:

```
<%=
box :option => 'value' do |b|
   b.header "Header of box #1"
   %>
   Content of Box#1
   <%
end
%>
```

The b.header call is optional.

How would I structure my code to allow this? I guess it's something similar to fields_for in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You could always look at the source for form_for / fields_for?

Comment: Good point, but I'm having a hard time deciphering the source code :-)